# SQL order by ABS()

Tags: mysql, sql

table_1

```
 column_1     
    .5          
    1          
    1.5         
    2         
    2.5          
    3           

SELEct column_1 FROM table_1 order by ABS(column_1 - 1.2) limit 1
```

I want result 1.5 But it is showing 1
But if i change value 1.3 then it show 1.5 but i enter 1.2

But i want to get update value which is 1.5 as i enter 1.2

Comment: I don't understand at all :D `I want result 1.5 But it is showing 1 But if i change value 1.3 then it show 1.5 but i enter 1.2` Whaaaaaat? this seems to be working as expected

Comment: Assuming I'm deciphering that correctly... `abs(1 - 1.2) = 0.2`. `abs(1.5 - 1.2) = 0.3`. Why would you expect 0.3 to be sorted before 0.2?

Comment: Is it that you want the nearest larger number to the input?

Comment: Do you want the value in your table _closest_ to `1.2`?  Something else?

Comment: The easiest way to get the "desired" result is by using `LIMIT 1, 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want 1.5, then you do not want to order by `abs(column_1 - 1.2)`.

I can speculate that you want the first value *larger than or equal to* 1.2.  If so:

```
SELECT column_1
FROM table_1 
WHERE column_1 >= 1.2
ORDER BY column_1
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: If that is indeed what OP wanted then just order by column_1.

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 3):

```
0.5 - 1.2 = (-)0.7 <--- third
1 - 1.2 = (-)0.2 <--- first
1.5 - 1.2 = 0.3 <--- second
2 - 1.2 = 0.8 <--- fourth
2.5 - 1.2 = 1.3 <--- fifth 
3 - 1.2 = 1.8 <--- sixth
```